# Validation for composite field in Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Let say I have a form with 10 input fields. `field3`, `field4`, `field5` are related - validity of `field4`'s and `field5`'s user input subjects to `field3`'s value.

Scenario:

1. User enters a value into `field4`. Its validator method (bound with `rules` prop) is auto-fired.

   ==> validation failed, `field4` is placed under error state.
2. User edits input in `field3`. Watcher for `field3` value is triggered, programmatically invokes the validator method of `field4`: `this.$refs.field4.validate(q4.answer)`

   ==> validation passed, I expect `field4` state to change from error to success, but it actually remains in error state.

After series of experiment, I believe Vuetify components have two set of validation state, one for auto-fired validation, and another one for manual triggered.

From Vuetify's API docs, I found a `form.resetValidation()` method but it reset the former state for **all fields** within a form, thus produced UX doesn't make sense for above use case. I couldn't find anything in API docs for resetting validation state of just the targeted field.

What's the proper way to implement validation for above scenario, without producing poor/confusing UX?

----- updated with relevant code snippet

My generic proxy input field that wrapping Vuetify's input field looks like the following:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    ...
    :rules="[validate]"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  props: {
    ... other props

    additionalValidations: {
      type: Function,
      default: null,
    },
  }, // props


  methods: {
    validate(input) {
      let validationError = null
      ... generic validations

      // Perform additional validations only if basic validations passed.
      if (!validationError && this.additionalValidations) {
        const result = this.additionalValidations(input) // returns either true or err msg.
        if (result !== true) {
          validationError = result
        }
      }

      return validationError || true
    }, // validate()
  }, // methods
}
</script>
```

Custom validation logic that compares multiple fields input is defined in parent component (such as page), then passed to above proxy input field via the `additionalValidations` prop.

Comment: Can you provide the code of validation that how exactly the `field 4's` validation is happening based on the `field 3's` value?

Comment: Did you try giving each field a ref and resetting using that ref? For example, `field 4` can have a ref attribute, `ref=field4Ref`, and to reset it-  `this.$refs.field4Ref.reset();`

Comment: @NehaSoni Refer added snippet on how I did cross field validation. I didn't try reset() as it's not listed under supported methods in Vuetify's docs. Even if Vuetify input components secretly support HTML's reset(), that's not what I need. I don't want to reset user input (the input has passed latest round of validation) - I only want to reset the validation state that won't go away.